# CakePHP model's find() not hitting mysql index b/c of integer strings

Tags: mysql, cakephp, numeric, database-indexes

While using a code like this:

```
$Model->find('all', array(
  'conditions' => array(
    'field' => '1111'
  )
));
```

where field is varchar mysql field cake generates a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Models WHERE field = 1111;
```

instead of expected

```
SELECT * FROM Models WHERE field = '1111';
```

This also makes mysql cast the entire DB to int instead of using string index.
I'm trying to optimize an already working system written by someone else, and a quick-grep shows thousands of find's I need to "fix". So an only acceptable solution should be either model-layer or mysql-layer.

tl;dr: How to make Cake pass integer strings from conditions to mysql as string and not as numbers?

Comment: you are obviously working on the wrong bottle neck... jesus, you are using cake - after all. it is not the fastest framework anyway. optimizing on the database level - at such a tiny use case - is absolutely irrelevant to the whole dispatcher process. just be using the find() wrappers you are destroying a million of those cast optimization fixes. but what the heck, nobody cares. because although it is slow, it is the most powerful and awesome framework out there. so keep on coding and dont bother about those little things.

Answer (score 0):

After running out of chars in the comment.
Would you should really be doing:

Optimizing at the PHP (Cake) level.
the find() wrappers are not ideal. they incredibly powerful but very slow. they allow rapid development but need more queries than necessary.

so there you should try to do some bottle neck fixing.
the DB is probably (internally) still the fastest piece in the dispatcher chain - with or without casts.

To get more concrete:

- use manual query() if you feel you have to
- try to use atomic methods (updateAll, deleteAll) where possible
- try to use containable and linkable behavior (especially the last) if you use find() calls with joins to cut down the amount of queries
- cache your db results somehow